# Как защитить данные авторизации в C#

Tags: c#, .net

Как их можно защитить если они изначально интегрированны в софт ?

Допустим софт авторизируется на сервер с помощью логина и пароля, этот логин и пароль зашит в софте.

Либо же нужно придумывать какое-то шифрование ключи - лицензию ?

Comment: Странный и непонятный вопрос. Не вшивайте в софт данные авторизации. Пусть логин/пароль вводит пользователь, ПО их не хранит -- а просто передаёт на сервер. Чем такая схема не устраивает? По-моему это настолько классика, что непонятно, зачем делать иначе.

Comment: хешируйте данные

Answer (score 0):

Любая информация перестает быть защищенной после того, как вы отправляете её клиенту.
Учитывая то, что в сборке присутствуют метаданные, защитить конфиденциальную информацию будет ещё сложнее, чем в каком-нибудь `c/c++`.

Поэтому лучшим решением будет не класть в клиент никаких данных, которые могут быть использованы не по назначению.

Comment: Мне нужен какой-то примитивный вариант, но так чтобы был более мение защищенный. На ум приходит, что-то типа такого, в софт зашить запрос к серверу с персональным ключем, а ответ будет зашифрованными логином и паролем к примеру которые в последсвии будет расшифровывать софт и уже авторизироваться ? Тут именно идея в том чтобы не узнали к примеру логин и пароль

Comment: @webstackoverload, Я не мастер в области защиты конфиденциальных данных, но мне как-то в свое время был нужен доступ к API Blizzard, и я не хотел токен хранить в клиенте, т.к. это позволило бы третьим лицам использовать мой токен в своих грязных целях и действовать от лица моего приложения. Мне пришлось сделать свой сервер, который выступал посредником между пользовательским приложением и серверами Battle.net. Приложение отправляло запрос на мой сервер, тот, в свою очередь, выполнял запрос к web API и возвращал результат приложению. Возможно, это будет выходом для вас.

Comment: Интересное решение. А что делать в случае работы по FTP ?

Comment: @webstackoverload, Не имел дела с этим протоколом, не могу ничего сказать.

Comment: Вопрос, по поводу реализации вашего метода, если в кратце, какие технологии использовали, именно с этим сталкиваюсь впервые, хотелось бы знать какие есть варианты вообще (по созданию API) на сервере

Comment: @webstackoverload, В самом приложении хватило двух классов System.Net.WebRequest и System.Net.WebResponse. Серверную часть можно писать на чем угодно, лишь бы умела обрабатывать GET и POST запросы, я предпочел ASP.NET.

Comment: @webstackoverload, вот тебе простейший сервер, который сможет отвечать на твои запросы. По ссылке и клиент и сервер: https://github.com/Casper-SC/NancyFxClientServer Там используется фреймворк NancyFx. Можешь использовать ASP.NET Core. Нагуглить примеры использования дело пары минут.

Comment: @webstackoverload, SSL шифрование в NancyFx: https://coderead.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/enabling-ssl-for-self-hosted-nancy/ 
Сам фреймворк http://nancyfx.org . На гитхабе есть исходники и другая информация о нём (в том числе SSL). https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Accessing-the-client-certificate-when-using-SSL

Comment: А что по поводу REST API, просто пришлось столнуться именно с сетевой стороной, а тут камней, не мало, особенно по поводу простоты и защищенность. За ссылки thx. Посмотрю